# Algorithm of best mapping from one point set to another

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have two point sets A={a1,a2,...,am} and B={b1,b2,...,bn} (m>=n), and want to find a injection map f from B to A such that it minimizes the sum of distances between each pair of points bi and f(bi). There may be duplicate points within A or B. Is anyone familiar with some algorithm related to this?

Thanks,

Niko

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: if duplicated points are allowed, why not always pick the shortest available pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) for minimum-weight matching is more applicable here than iterative closest point, since the map f is injective into A rather than an isometry. Make m - n dummy points at distance 0 from all points in A to match the points in A not matched with a point in B.

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that all that's needed is an injection, not a bijection. Good call!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the [iterative closest point algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point), which (I believe) is one of the standard algorithms used to solve this problem. It works by making an initial guess by mapping each point in one cloud to the closest point in another, computing a transformation or rotation to get one point cloud more aligned with the other, then repeating this process. There are also several implementations of this algorithm available online if you're curious.

Hope this helps!